# using Facebook koala gem to like a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

when using the koala gem, how do I like the current page?

I thought it would be something like this...but it's not working

```
@graph.put_like("http://www.currentpage.com")
```

@graph is an authenticated object, I have it working for put_connections, put_wall, etc...However, put_like keeps returning false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a `put_like` method in the koala or facebook api. `like` is a opengraph action. So you could do something like:

```
@graph.put_connections("me", "your_app_namespace:like", :object => "http://www.currentpage.com")
```

You have to create the `like action` in your facebook application and set a namespace for your app.

You can read more about [opengraph actions here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/).

Comment: Don't know if this wasn't the case back in July 2012, but now creating a custom like action for open graph results in this error: "A custom Like action is restricted. Please use the common Like action instead."

Answer (score 0):

Will this like the fan page and increase the follower count or just like the fan page url?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook won't let you create a custom like action for your application.  You have to use their common like action without the application namespace:

```
@graph.put_connections("me", "og.likes", object: "http://www.currentpage.com")
```

I believe .put_like only works by referring to specific object names or IDs.  If you are simply liking a URL, use the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook just updated [their docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes) on this matter on November 17, 2016. Liking an object through the API is only possible now if you are using a page access token.

You can do this with the Koala gem like so:

```
client.put_connections(object_id, 'likes')
```